# Android Apps UI/UX

Tags: android

I am learning to design for Android and looking forward to do some research to understand how other are developing UI for apps on Android. Please share the best UI/UX android apps you have come across.

Comment: This question is subjective and a poll, and will probably get closed. See [FAQ](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: Perhaps a better fitting question would be to ask for Android UI guidelines; Google has released some themselves, though it's not as extensive as Apple's Human Interface Guidelines on iOS but it's a good start.

Comment: @harsha you should check the app market and screenshot of there apps, it will give you some idea's for sure else ask someone like us to design ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a lecture from Google I/O 2010 - [Android UI design patterns](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1ZBjlCRfz0) - touching common topics like Design Philosophy and Design Patterns like Dashboard and Quick Actions, which they recommend that you use.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of my personal favorite android apps with awe-inspiring UI.

Google+ 
Facebook 
Google Currents 
Twitter 
Tumblr